# HTML date input: set day (instead of year) with arrows

Tags: html, date

Is there a way to set the date HTML5 input to change the day instead of year with arrows?

Comment: what do you mean? the arrows changing every part of the date, starting with days - http://jsfiddle.net/tz4eV/

Comment: I mean when you first click on the arrow next to the date input (while nothing's selected) it's automatically selects the year, and changes it.

Comment: for me it selects the day first.. what browser are you using?

Comment: chrome 25.0.1364.172 m

Comment: can the problem is the different date format we use in our country (we use yyyy-mm-dd)?

Comment: The behavior of the html5 chrome date element depends on the culture of the browser: ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968817/is-there-a-way-to-localize-input-type-date-in-html5