# change <input type="date"> to Persian Date

Tags: javascript, html, date, input, persian-calendar

is there any way to simply change the `<input type="date">` output,  from Gregorian to Persian Date?
something like this:

```js
var localToday = new Date().toLocaleDateString('fa-IR');
console.log(localToday);
```

```html
<input type="date">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to localize input type="date" in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968817/is-there-a-way-to-localize-input-type-date-in-html5)

Comment: Actually, AFAIK this is not achievable, because the setting of `<input type="date">` in most browser strictly comes from browser settings. So since there is no Persian language in neither of the browsers this is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear from your answers and comments that I need to use JavaScript DatePicker to achieve my goal.
After a lot of searching for that, i think its the better one: [Link](https://behzadi.github.io/persianDatepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

Reading the HTML documentation, I don't think there is a way to show another calendar in the input field.

[input type="date"](https://devdocs.io/html/element/input/date)

[input type="datetime-local"](https://devdocs.io/html/element/input/datetime-local)